# SQL colum field with multiple fixed values

Tags: sql, database-design

Suppose you have a fixed list of values (strings): "None", "Skype", "ICQ", "GoogleTalk", "MSN" and others.

The user can select only one of that string as his main instant messaging application.

Call this field `IM` of a hypothetical table `ContactInformations`. Using a SQL table, how would you model the `IM` field? The solution should let the code that populates the listbox to load the possible choices from a database. When the user has made his selection and has pressed the "save" button, the code should update the `IM` field.

So, I would do something like this:

Table `ContactInformations` has the field `IM` of type `int`, referencing the `IMListID` field.
The `IMListID` is the key of the following table:

**IMNameList**

```
IMListID   int, primary key, not null
text       varchar(100)
```

So, when creating the DB, I would insert all the names of the Instant Messaging applications supported into the `IMList` table, I would put the `IM` field of `ContactInformations` to the default value `0` ("none").

Populating the list of possible IM applications names is easy (fetch it from `IMNameList` table), updating is less easy, because I make the implicit assumption that the key of "none" is 0, of "Skype" is 1, of "ICQ" is 2 and so on and I made another implicit assumption: when the user select "Skype" from the listbox, the index of "Skype" is 1.

How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use an id number for IM names.  They have sufficient identity all on their own.  Here's one way to do it using PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE IMNameList (
  IMName VARCHAR(35) PRIMARY KEY
);

insert into IMNameList values
('None'), 
('Skype'), 
('ICQ'), 
('GoogleTalk'), 
('MSN');
```

You also want an INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger (not shown) on IMNameList to prevent everybody from deleting the value 'None'. (That's true regardless of whether you use ID numbers. If you use ID number, you'll need an additional UNIQUE constraint on IMName.)

```
CREATE TABLE ContactInformations (
    user_id integer primary key,      -- references users, not shown
    IM VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'None' 
        REFERENCES IMNameList (IMName) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
);

INSERT INTO ContactInformations VALUES 
(1, 'Skype'),
(2, 'MSN');
```

With ON DELETE SET DEFAULT, you can delete rows from IMNameList without worrying about whether they're still in use. The underlying assumption is that you won't delete IM platforms that are still in existence.

```
DELETE FROM IMNameList
WHERE IMName = 'MSN';

SELECT * 
FROM ContactInformations;

user_id  IM
--
1        Skype
2        None
```

That takes care of the database side. On the application side, it's easy to get a list of valid IM platforms.

```
SELECT IMName
FROM IMNameList
ORDER BY IMName;
```

Updates to ContactInformations don't require knowing anything about IM id numbers. To change the first user's IM from 'Skype' to 'ICQ', just

```
UPDATE ContactInformations
SET IM = 'ICQ'
WHERE user_id = 1 
  AND IM = 'Skype';
```

Comment: I like your solution in principle. What concern me is the fact that the field IM is a varchar, so basically disk space is wasted. Furthermore, is using a varchar as a primary key slower?

Comment: With the values given, the average length of an entry is 5.5 bytes, or about 2 bytes bigger than a 32-bit integer. Using a varchar as a foreign key eliminates a join on every SELECT statement from now until the end of time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with updating the table if you fetch names of applications together with their IDs. The only thing I would change is to have "none" as NULL and not as 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common scenario and should be super easy to achieve, I have no idea what language you are using (is it even web?)

But usually, list controls can be data bound to a data source, and you can specify a "text field" and a "value field", the value field in your case would be the IM field, and the text field should be the IMName, which you should get out of a join with the other table, on the IM field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) type.

For a comparison of Enum and your solution, see the following thread.

[MySQL ENUM type vs join tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362044/mysql-enum-type-vs-join-tables)

Answer (score 0):

When working with pre-defined types that will never change by the user, I use an enum in my application.  This ensures that the correct integer is stored in the database.

enum IMListType { 
NotSet,
Skype,
ICQ,
MSN,
Yahoo
}

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what your question is. Maybe it is this: "When I add a new record to IMNameList, how do I make sure that I don't use a number that has already been used?"

If so, you are looking for an automatically-incrementing number for the IMListID field. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389641/does-oracle-have-auto-number-data-type) isn't phrased exactly like yours, but the accepted answer shows you a way to do it that works across all database platforms.

Comment: I have a "fixed" list of strings. This list change slowly. The user can select his IM app only from that list. The presentation layer of my app (web app, desktop app, it doen't make any difference) doesn't need to know the list, someone else will pass it to him. Further, when the user select "ICQ", i want to easily store in the IM field a reference to "ICQ" (not directly the string "ICQ"). Enum is probably not too well suited, since my list is not like ("Male", "Female"), which basically shouldn't change at all. A couple (string, id-code) should do the job.

Comment: I understand what you want to do and I agree that string, id-code will work fine. My issue is that you seem to have already solved the problem, so I don't know what you want us to say. I can't find a problem with updating any of your tables although you say that "updating is less easy."

Comment: Hi, i have made the question because i am not an expert on db design (and i have to design one for a project), and even if i have seen the right way to model that problem, i am interested in knowing if there are some other way (maybe a pattern, a standard way) to solve it! Thx all.